# client server semantic data transfer with GWT

Tags: gwt, semantic-web, restlet

In short, how do you transfer semantic data between client and server with GWT and which frameworks do you use? Read on for more details that I've thought about.

For example, using GWT 2.2.0 features like the RequestFactory will bring the constraint to have java beans transferred while the semantic resources are represented as triples and a resource can have a varying set of properties. So the RequestFactory itself cannot be shaped to transfer semantic-driven data easily.

A way to do that would be to use RequestFactory with beans that represent triples. Such bean would have 3 properties: subject, predicate, object. These beans will be transferred to client which will know to query, change their properties and then send them to server. This approach will however need a custom implementation(there are no GWT-based frameworks to represent semantic data on client-side, from what I've searched so far) and that could prove buggy or unoptimized. I've seen this approach in this project: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-odb-ui/ - it used GWT-RPC and implements some classes that represent semantic resources. However, I think it's in an incipient stage so I'm reluctant to copy their model.

Also, I've found that Restlets is a framework that supports the semantic web approach to applications. However, there is no documentation or an example on how to use Restlets with Semantic Web and perhaps with GWT. Also, Restlets is also supporting GWT. Does anyone know if this is a viable solution or not?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Restlet should work quite well for you. It has a GWT edition able to automatically serialize your triple beans. In addition, it also comes with an org.restlet.ext.rdf extension, including a Link class similar to your triple bean idea.

For further documentation, I would suggest the "[Restlet in Action](http://www.manning.com/affiliate/idevaffiliate.php?id=1121_217)" book which covers GWT and the semantic web from a Restlet and REST point of view.